# Reduce HTTP requests bundling bower_components together?

Tags: node.js, bower, gulp

I'm developing a web application and I'm using about 20 bower_components (bootstrap, jquery, some jquery plugin like cookie and serializejson, mousewheel, mustache, underscore etc).

All these plugins are quite small (except for bootstrap and jquery), but are loaded with a dedicated "" tag.

This makes my page asks for 20 micro javascript files and this makes the page load slowly.

I'd like to bundle all these scripts together and load the bundle...

I've tried with gulp-bower-src but it just help me to uglify them and move them in a "lib" folder... Can't find a way to compress them all together.

This is my gulp task atm

```
var filter = gulpFilter("**/*.js", "!**/*.min.js");

gulp.task("default", function () {
    bowerSrc()
    .pipe(filter)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(filter.restore())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + "/public/lib"));
});
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-concat) to bundle all these micro files into one asset.

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var filter = gulpFilter("**/*.js", "!**/*.min.js");

gulp.task("default", function () {
    bowerSrc()
    .pipe(filter)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(filter.restore())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(__dirname + "/public/lib"));
});
```

This will concat all filtered and uglified files as `bundle.js` into directory `public/lib`. Keep in mind that when concatenating these files the order of files matters. I guess that gulp-bower-src does not order scripts according to a dependency graph (I found nothing in the documentation) so it might require you to select the bower files by hand in the right order.

A manual ordering/selecting of the bower components could be done by substituting the `bowerSrc()` by a line somehow like this

```
gulp.src(['./bower_components/jquery/jquery.js', './bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js', './bower_components/jquery-swift-color-picker/color.js']);
```

This may seem a little clumsy and it is but order matters.

Comment: thank you, how can I specify the order of the files?

Comment: I added an example to do the selecting and ordering of the bower components.